# Self Sizing Collection View Cell in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I implemented UICollection view cell with Auto Layout. It works fine.

But my cell height is dynamic so cell should be change its height as per constraint set.

but height is not changed in any case.

**My Code**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

        UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowlayout = (UICollectionViewFlowLayout*)_col.collectionViewLayout;
        flowlayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width - 30, 600);
}

-(UICollectionViewCell*)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    FirstCell *cell = [_col dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FirstCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return  cell;
}
```

**Storyboard**

[image]

**Simulator**

[image]

**All labels are multi lined**

**Help me to solve this**

**thanks for your time**

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below thing to achieve self sizing collection cell.

1) Same as table cells, use constraints or override -sizeThatFits:.

2) Override -[UICollectionReusableView preferredLayoutAttributesFittingAttributes:] to adjust layout attributes determined by the UICollectionViewLayout.

3) New estimatedItemSize property on UICollectionViewFlowLayout, equivalent to estimatedRowHeight on UITableView.

Comment: matt is right, you need to set it by overriding collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

There are no self-sizing collection view cells in iOS before iOS 10. (Apple has claimed in WWDC videos that this feature exists, but it doesn't.)

You have to implement the delegate method [`collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout/collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAtIndexPath:) to provide a size for each cell. It can call [`systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:) to use the internal constraints to do that, if you like; but the runtime will not magically do it for you.

Comment: But if I take single label then all is working fine with same code.

Comment: That's great to hear. But I stand by what I said.

Comment: `[cell systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize]` returns (0,0) as CGSize
why?

Comment: Because your internal constraints do not completely fill out the inside of the cell. You need enough constraints to give the cell its width and height from the inside out.

Comment: But all labels have top,bottom,left,right constraints.isn't it all enough?

Comment: That doesn't say what the _width and height_ of the label should be. You said yourself: "All labels are multi lined." Okay, then. Suppose the text is long. What should happen? Should the text wrap? If so, at what width? Merely having TBLR constraints won't tell us that. So your constraints cannot be interpreted. Remember, you can't size in relation to the cell, because the size of the cell is the unknown in the equation. You must size _from the inside out_.

Comment: I also set Compression resistance Priority as 1000 then it takes height according to content

Comment: "I also set Compression resistance Priority as 1000" There are infinite wrong things you can do. It is best to do it right.

Comment: "There are infinite wrong things you can do" means?

Comment: You tell me. Did setting the compression resistance priority to 1000 cause my answer to work?